# How to import the public GPG key for OpenSearch in Ubuntu based environment?

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, centos, opensearch

Trying to install OpenSearch in an Ubuntu-based environment. Recently moved over from old CentOS machine. What is the equivalent command below for ubuntu-based machines?

```
sudo rpm --import https://artifacts.opensearch.org/publickeys/opensearch.pgp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gpg --import`.
In your case I would do
`wget -o opensearchkey https://artifacts.opensearch.org/publickeys/opensearch.pgp`
and then
`gpg --import opensearchkey`
You can list the newly imported key by `gpg --list-keys`